# How to install tidymodels package in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

My version of Rstudio is 4.0.4, and I installed tidymodels package in Jupyter notebook.
However, it showed that

> Warning message:
> "package 'tidymodels' was built under R version 3.6.3"

I can not use this package. Can someone help me ,please?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to update `broom` ?

Comment: @Basti  I jsut tried, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The update of `broom` doesn't work or `library(tidymodels)`still doesn't work ?

Comment: I have updated the broom using install.packages("broom"), but the library(tidymodels) still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you explicit the error you have now and what is the output of `packageVersion("broom")` ?